nextjs - supabase/ssr - row level security
in one of my projects I'm using the new @supabase/ssr authentication lib. So far everything works. But when I enable RLS on the supabase table I canot figure out how to write a RLS so that only a known user can do some operation. ( like a user can only select own items (user_id = auth.uid()) ).
I used this doc: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client
I found on github the following conversation: https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/6592#discussioncomment-3113347
The problem is that the given methods do not exists anymore. It is also described in the docs of  supabase/ssr that the server does not have the information about the user and it needs to be called and send with the request, but it is not described how.
Has anybody knowledge about how to setup supabase/ssr with nextjs in order to work with RLS?
I tried to setup an RLS with (user_id = auth.uid()) like the template that supabase is providing. But with this RLS a user still is now allowed to do so.
I would expect that when I setup everthing from https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client and I choose an given RLS template that it works.

I spend the last two days to figure out that there was an import problem.
For everybody who followed the https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client instruction. Rename the export of the client- and server-client that is exported. Because both having the same name "createClient" that lead in my case that VSCode imported the supabase client for the browser instead for the server.
